# "Last Activity" for Environments in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

What is the meaning of the "Last Activity" column on the Environments page in Azure DevOps?

It is **not** the date of the last deployment. It is **not** the date of the last pipeline run. Could it be that date the pipeline was last edited? (How is that useful?)

A much more worthwhile column would be "Last Deployment Date". Is there a setting I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Last Activity" column on the Environments page represents the  "Last modified time of the Environment".

Please take a look at the two comparison images below:

1.I have a Environment named `smarthotel-dev` that  column `Last Activity` is `Sep 28 2022`.
[image]

2.Click the environment and select `Edit` button to modify the env and then click `Save` button.

3.Refresh the Environment page and you will see the column `Last Activity` is
`Jan 15,2024`.
[image]
So the column `Last Activity` will be updated after making changes to the environment.

You can also refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to know more information about Environment.

> A much more worthwhile column would be "Last Deployment Date".

There isn't a direct `Last Deployment Date` column available in the default view of Azure DevOps Environments.
If you want to see `Last Deployment Date`, you can click the env and it will direct you to `Deployments` page to check the date.

Besides you may access this URL:  https://aka.ms/AzDevOpsIdeas to submit any comments and proposals for future releases and implementations.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Personally, I think the column is poorly named, and misleading. And even with a better name, is it worth a column to display the last date of a name/description change? Hardly.